# How to regenerate Data Map in Pamguard Viewer

Tags: pamguard, datamap

When a database is opened for the first time in Pamguard Viewer Mode, it usually prompts for you to specify the resolution of the datamap. The default is 600 seconds. To be more specific, in my case I am opening a database that was run on previously collected data, not towed array data in real time.

I am working with a relatively small dataset so I would actually like the Data Map to have a resolution of 30 seconds. I accidentally clicked through the 600 second default but now I cannot figure out how to remake the data map with my desired settings.

I tried deleting the 'serialisedBinaryMap.data' file that is created within the 'binaries' folder, but that is not reprompting me to modify the settings.

Is there a method through the Pamguard Viewer menus that I can regenerate the Data Map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the feature you are requesting can be found under:

File -> Binary Store -> Datagram options.

[image: Pamguard: File -> Binary Store -> Datagram Options]

This then should display a new dialog to adjust the time bins for the Datagram.

[image: Pamguard:Datagram Settings dialog]

Note that the value entered here is expected to be in seconds, so a value of 600 here would be 10 minutes.

Hope this helps!

Cheers,
Brian

Tested on Pamguard Version 2.01.05.

Comment: Ah, yes there it is! Thanks so much. And I also edited my question to correct 'minutes' to 'seconds'. Apparently asking this too late at night/when too tired :)